# How is SQL Server removing spaces?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following constraint...

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_No_Spaces] CHECK  ((charindex(' ',[mobile])=(0)))
```

If I run the following in Management Studio, it fails.

```
UPDATE table1 SET mobile = '1 2 3'
```

If I run the same query from an app, such that the query appears in the profiler and the spaces are in the string, it automatically strips them out.

How is this possible?

It does it on my staging database but not on my local dev database.

**EDIT:** It seems that the staging database isn't throwing an exception. And the update doesn't happen after all.

Comment: what do you mean by `it automatically strips them out` ?

Comment: I meant that the illegal values are made legal by removing the spaces. But I was fooled. I was editing a value like 123 to 12 3 and it was simply not updating the database at all. It was staying as 123. For some reason, the staging database wasn't throwing an error so the app didn't forward that on to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

seems you are trying to update your column `'mobile'` to restrict  values to only allow with spaces.

using this one, will allow `'1 2 3'`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_No_Spaces] CHECK  ((charindex(' ',[mobile])>(0)))
```

using this one, will restrict `'1 2 3'`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_No_Spaces] CHECK  ((charindex(' ',[mobile])=(0)))
```

You need to check your staging and local databases first.

```
select count(1) from table1 where charindex(' ',[mobile])>0
```